# Computer shutdown while upgrading ubuntu (Partition)

Tags: 16.04, boot, 18.04

My computer shut down while updating from ubuntu 16 to 18 and now I cannot even acces the log-in menu.

Anyway to turn this back or at least recover my files?

(It's a partition with Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Just boot Ubuntu from a Stick, save your data and reinstall it.

Or use chroot to fix your system: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is a dual-boot machine with Windows 10 Professional, then avoid
simply dual-boot.

Because it is that Windows 10 has embedded Ubuntu in area of kernel. So this partition is than mis-taken, when updates are performed ?